# How to filter XmlNode?

Tags: .net, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, json.net

i am working on filtering xml nodes in XmlNode.innerXML ,i get innerXML with list of xml element as below :

```
<runQueryRecord><id>128</id><caption_id>32</caption_id><featurename>DVC.CANYON-NIGHTFALL</featurename><featureprice>0</featureprice><sorting>0</sorting><partnumber></partnumber><imagepath>assets/images/DVC/NIGHTFALL.jpg</imagepath><selected>0</selected><hidden>0</hidden><optcatalogid>0</optcatalogid><advopt_code></advopt_code><qty>1</qty><featurecost>0</featurecost></runQueryRecord>
```

now i want to search nodes having specific value in featurename tag.and then i have to convert it to json.

my whole code is :

```
XmlNode node = advanceAPI.runQuery("----", "--------",sqlquery);
var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("APIResponse(");
            sb.Append(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(node,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
            sb.Append(");");
```

i tried following way:

```
node = node.SelectNodes("//runQueryRecord[contains(featurename,'"+ Request.QueryString["strOption"] +"')]");
```

but this gives me XMLNodeList which is not proper format to convert it in JSON for Newtonsoft.Json.

please give some ideas about filter XMLNode node and getting matching node with condition.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want only a single XmlNode rather than an XmlNodeList, you can use [`SelectSingleNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b.aspx) instead of [`SelectNodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This will give the first node that matches the XPath query.

Second, if you want to convert XML to JSON, you need to use [`JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeXmlNode.htm) not [`JsonConvert.SerializeObject`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm).

Here is a demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = @"
            <runQueryRecord>
                <id>128</id>
                <caption_id>32</caption_id>
                <featurename>DVC.CANYON-NIGHTFALL</featurename>
                <featureprice>0</featureprice>
                <sorting>0</sorting>
                <partnumber></partnumber>
                <imagepath>assets/images/DVC/NIGHTFALL.jpg</imagepath>
                <selected>0</selected>
                <hidden>0</hidden>
                <optcatalogid>0</optcatalogid>
                <advopt_code></advopt_code>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <featurecost>0</featurecost>
            </runQueryRecord>";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);

        string qsOption = "DVC.CANYON-NIGHTFALL";
        XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//runQueryRecord[contains(featurename,'" + qsOption + "')]");
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Formatting.Indented);

        Console.WriteLine("APIResponse(" + json + ");");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
APIResponse({
  "runQueryRecord": {
    "id": "128",
    "caption_id": "32",
    "featurename": "DVC.CANYON-NIGHTFALL",
    "featureprice": "0",
    "sorting": "0",
    "partnumber": null,
    "imagepath": "assets/images/DVC/NIGHTFALL.jpg",
    "selected": "0",
    "hidden": "0",
    "optcatalogid": "0",
    "advopt_code": null,
    "qty": "1",
    "featurecost": "0"
  }
});
```